# Can $E=mc^2$ be also expressed as $mc=\sqrt E$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

As the title suggests, can the equation $E=mc^2$ be also expressed as $mc=\sqrt{E}$?

Comment: If $E=mc^2$, then $\sqrt{E}=\sqrt{m}c$.

Comment: You're taking the square root of both sides of the equation. As such, the m gets square rooted as well.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A physical remark: the relativistic energy of a particle with (rest) mass $m$ and momentum $p$ is given by
$$E = \sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4},$$
which reduces to $E=mc^2$ for particles at rest (in a given inertial system).

Comment: @Daniel: So in a universe where $c=0$, we get that $E=0$ as well. Neat. No light = no energy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, but that would be a reeeeeally unphysical universe... You really want $c>0$. (You can think of $c$ as parametrizing the "time" in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so putting $c=0$ you would in some sense completely lose the time dimension.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Or maybe a better way to put it is: the Minkowski metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ (giving special relativity) is $c^2dt^2-(dx^1)^2-(dx^2)^2-(dx^3)^2$, so if $c=0$ you don't get a pseudo-Riemannian metric.

Comment: @Daniel: Well then. I guess it's just a fantastic universe. If you are a photon, moving at the speed of light, then everything else is frozen to you, right? You're living in a timeless universe. That's roughly equal to $c=0$, no?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Mmmh, maybe, my physics isn't that strong ;)

(Even though for what I know for photons *proper* time - that is, a parameter reparametrizing the curve to "unit" speed - is constant in some sense. But I don't think that the distribution given by light-like vectors is integrable, which would in some sense give a "$c=0$" submanifold...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, since it just asks about a mistake of elementary algebra, there is no archival use for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you square root both sides of the equation, then all of $mc$ must be square rooted $(ie. \sqrt{mc^2} = \sqrt {E}$).

So then simplifying:

$$ c\sqrt{m} = \sqrt {E}$$

Comment: Hmm... you're saying square root all of $mc$, but the square root wraps only $m$?

Comment: Should be all of $mc^2$.

Comment: @joltmode Yes because $c^2$ is already squared, so when $c^2$ is square rooted, then it becomes $c$. However, $m$ is not already squared, so it has the square root sign.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Einstein was quite a smart lad, ha..

Comment: Furthermore from a strictly mathematical point of view the equation $E=mc^2$ is not same as $\sqrt{E}=\sqrt{m}c$ because when you square root $E=mc^2$ in both sides, you get $\sqrt{E}=\pm\sqrt{m}c$, not only $\sqrt{E}=\sqrt{m}c$.

Comment: Why not $\sqrt{ \frac {e} {m} }  = c$?

Answer (score 4):

No, because $mc^2$ on the right-hand side should be read as $m\cdot(c^2)$.

Comment: Ah yeah, the hidden/obvious multiplication sign...

Answer (score 2):

No.Even the units doesn't match ,Left hand side -> $kg\cdot m/s^2$ and right hand side is $(kg\cdot m)^{1/2} /s$